# How could we prevent answered ID questions from being bumped by Community?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I think there is no point in bumping answered ID questions that were answered correctly, like these two:

- [Punk rock music video with exploding mailboxes](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/4333/punk-rock-music-video-with-exploding-mailboxes)
- [What song plays in the background during this Russillo & Kanell sports broadcast?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/4070/what-song-plays-in-the-background-during-this-russillo-kanell-sports-broadcast)

I like the idea of poking up unanswered question to get them attention, but questions like these are randomly bumped in the main page once in a while, and there is nothing to do because the answer is correct.

Could we mark, somehow, the question/answer so it is not selected by [Community](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) to be bumped?

Comment: As long as there is one answer is positive, the question will not be bumped as it is considered "answered".

Comment: @Dom I'm aware of that. The specific situation I'm talking about is when the sum of votes is still zero and the answer is correct. Theses questions have been bumped several times before I ask here.

Answer (score 2):

That would be a bad idea.

One of the reason these answers are bumped by Community is to make sure they get some attention. The reason they're bumped is usually because they lack the aforementioned attention.

Look whether both question and answer are any good. Vote. Move on.

The answers mentioned are (at the moment, I'm going to fix that after writing this answer) correct, not marked as accepted and have 0 votes. That's respectively good, unfortunate and easy to fix.

Good answers should be awarded upvotes, bad answers downvotes. Community simply helps by pointing towards the answers we might have missed. It even says so in the message affixed under the question:

[image: Community message: This question has answers that may be good or bad; the system has marked it active so that they can be reviewed.]

> This question has answers that may be good or bad; the system has marked it active so that they can be reviewed.

Review them and all is well.

Comment: You are right. The thing is, I upvoted them but someone downvoted so they are still zero.

Comment: @Bebs There's a definite lack of voting going on here, so one vote carries a lot of weight at the moment.